# Is there something like Mt.Gox Live but for Intersango?

Tags: charts, intersango, live-data

Is there something like Mt.Gox Live but for Intersango?

I don't expect the same quality, but at least to be better than this horrible bugged mess which is BitcoinCharts/BitcoinWatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be a chart like that for this website. Not every exchange provides a live chart on its own, and asides the two websites you mentioned, there aren't any other that would provide access to a more "live" feed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try slush's SierraChart bridge which supports all markets supported by bitcoincharts:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6019.0

Answer (score 1):

One does not exist but I have it on my TODO list (which is quite long).

Comment: GL HF! (9 more to go...)